# Math Lesson Name

Tags: advice

I live in a developing country and the education systems in my country is not very good. I'm studying in second year of high school and I always wanted to improve my math and others skills so I learn online in my free time. I learned lots of things but the problem is I don't know how to search for because I don't know what all of those words mean in English.

**If there are some people that are studying math or any subject in English, could you list all of the topic(lesson) for me, please. Any help would be appreciate.**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Subject_Classification

Comment: See also the [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) part of the Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Moo This is an ingenious suggestion, but the MSC was designed to sort out research papers, and might not be too useful for high school students.

Comment: @kimchilover: However, it might still provide the words needed for a non-English speaker and that is why it is a comment. Regards.

Comment: For high school level math words in English, see [this web page](https://www.thoughtco.com/glossary-of-mathematics-definitions-4070804) and [this web page](https://www.barcodesinc.com/articles/mathematical-terms-dictionary.htm). See also the terms listed for [high school mathematics in Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/high-school-math).